# Android studio Linear layout question : How should I layout mine without a nested weights?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX9yI.png)

For the tree I made `LinearLayout` (horizontal). It has an image and other `LinearLayout` which has text and button.

I tried to give weight to text and button, it keeps I am using nested weights. How should I fix it without an error?

Comment: post layout xml code here.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the `LinearLayout` here, there's no way around without nested weights. Google recommends using [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) to keep the layout's hierarchy low.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/glCenterVertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/glCenterVertical"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<Space
    android:id="@+id/space"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/space"
    android:text="Test"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"
    android:text="Test"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/space"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/></androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Some tip - you can replace your fixed size dimensions (for example `android:layout_height="150dp"`) with ``app:layout_constraintWidth_percent`` and `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent` to make your layout responsive to all screen sizes. Good answer

Comment: I have to use LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, and/or FrameLayout only.